# how do I insert into a textBox a value from MS-Access in visual studio c# using OleDb?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-access

I'm trying to get a value from access and put it in a string variable or a textBox, I'm using MS-Visual Studio 2012 and Access 2007

```
string sql = "SELECT [Time Checked-In] FROM HotelCustomers WHERE [Room Number] =" + textBox1.Text + ";";
        string my_Connection = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source= c:\\Users\\Acer\\Documents\\HotelCustomersOld.mdb";
        OleDbConnection myCon = new OleDbConnection(my_Connection);
        myCon.Open();
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, my_Connection);
        adapter.Fill(dataTable);
        string aString = dataTable.Rows[0]["Time Checked-In"].ToString();
        textBox1.Text = aString;
```

Comment: where is your code? have you tried something?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please, when asking you need to show the code that is causing you problems otherwise it is a guess post a valid answer

Comment: and now what's the problem? what error are you getting?

Comment: ExecuteReader: Connection property has not been initialized.

Comment: I know this might be studpid, but this is my first time using c# and connecting to a database

Comment: I don't think that you have opened the connection:
    add con.open();
under the OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(My_Connection);

Comment: I've opened the connection, I've changed the code another error came up: Data type mismatch in criteria expression. ----> at the line adapter.Fill(dataTable);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is likely because of the name used in your HotelCustomers table. It is likely that OleDb is changing it to something that is legal for it to use.

You could re-write your SQL to use something more OleDb friendly:

```
  string sql = "SELECT [Time Checked-In] AS CheckIN FROM HotelCustomers WHERE [Room Number] =" + textBox1.Text + ";";
```

That said, you do not need the overhead of the `OleDbDataAdapter` or `DataTable` for this simple query.

```
private const string CONN_STR = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source= c:\\Users\\Acer\\Documents\\HotelCustomersOld.mdb";

private string GetCheckInTime(string roomNumber) {
  string sql = "SELECT [Time Checked-In] AS CheckIN FROM HotelCustomers WHERE [Room Number] =" + roomNumber + ";";
  object obj = null;
  using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, new OleDbConnection(CONN_STR))) {
    cmd.Connection.Open();
    obj = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    cmd.Connection.Close();
  }
  if ((obj != null) && (obj != DBNull.Value)) {
    return obj.ToString();
  }
  return null;
}
```

The connection string will never change, so I made it a constant.

Comment: it's almost done, but another error came up: Data type mismatch in criteria expression. at line:   obj = cmd.ExecuteScalar();